# CakePHP -- Efficient counting of unique properties in a related model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a Post model that has an associated Comment model. Each comment has a user_id associated with a User model...all very standard stuff.

Essentially, when I fo a find query on all the Posts I'm interested in, I am looking for a way to efficiently get the number of unique user_id's that have commented on each Post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used `counterCache`? That will probably get you where you need to be. You will also want to combine that with some fancy conditions on `counterScope`. This will allow you to save the number of commenters when a record is saved/updated, instead of on the fly; resulting in a faster page and a better user experience.

Now, this alone may not get you to the final solution. Consider using a combination of counterCache/counterScope and virtualFields to pull the data and update that way.

[Read about counterCache in the Book](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1033/counterCache-Cache-your-count)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming Post hasMany Comment relationship, so the find results look something like this:

```
$posts = array(
0 => array
(
    'Post' => array
    (
        'id' => 1
        , 'Comment' => array
        (
            0 => array
            (
                'id' => 1          
            )
            , 1 => array
            (
                'id' => 2
            )
        )
    )       
)
, 1 => array
(
    'Post' => array
    (
        'id' => 2         
        , 'Comment' => array
        (
            0 => array
            (
                'id' => 3
            )
        )
    )
)
, 2 => array
(
    'Post' => array
    (
        'id' => 3
        , 'Comment' => array
        (
            0 => array
            (
                'id' => 4
            )
            , 1 => array
            (
                'id' => 5
            )
            , 2 => array
            (
                'id' => 6
            )
        )
    )
));
```

You can then use the [Set class](http://debuggable.com/posts/cake-12s-set-class-eats-arrays-for-breakfast:480f4dd6-d084-4fb7-bacc-49fdcbdd56cb) to extract just the id's like this:

```
$userIds = Set::extract($posts, '{n}.Post.Comment.{n}.id');
```

And if there are duplicates you can call array_unique:

```
$userIds = array_unique($userIds);
```

That should do it!